# Help me figure out where to place 'object pronoun'?

Tags: pronouns

I try to figure out if there is a need for placing "them" after the verb"translate"?

> 1)Regarding the list,it comes with partial Japanese that needs you to translate into English terms for our tech staff.
>
> 2)Regarding the list,it comes with partial Japanese that needs you to translate **them** into English terms for our tech staff.

Comment: I think questions like this might fit better on the English Language Learners site (although proof-reading by itself is not on topic there or here, you can ask about specific grammar points): http://ell.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of your examples were correct, instead try one of these:

Passive:

> Regarding the list, it comes with partial Japanese that **needs to be translated** into English terms for our tech staff.

Imperative:

> Regarding the list, it comes with partial Japanese that **you need to translate** into English terms for our tech staff.

Also, in the first part of the sentence "it comes with partial Japanese" doesn't seem right, but I can't correct this without knowing the context. It might be better to say "it contains some Japanese".

Comment: @jhabbott +1 How about this one: "Regarding the list, it comes with partial Japanese that requires you to translate into English terms for our tech staff."

Comment: @haha no, that suffers the same problem. The word 'that' changes the 'subject' of the sentence from 'the list' to 'the Japanese'. Neither 'the list' nor 'the Japanese' can require you to do anything, that would suggest they have some conscious needs. It would be like saying "The bicycle needs you to clean it.", which is not true. However, "The bicycle needs to be cleaned." is ok, even though the reason and the person needing it to be done are not stated - these can be assumed by the reader.

Comment: jhabbott, thanks for the explicit explanation for a non-native english speaker like me!